# Converting MultiPartFile to XWPFDocument

Tags: java, spring, apache, ms-word, apache-poi

I need to know how to convert a multipartFile to a XWPFDocument in order to read it as a word file ( the file that I uploaded is in fact a .docx ) however I receive the error :

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/UnsupportedFileFormatException
```

Here is my code :

```
@Override
  public void addReport(MultipartFile report) throws ApcException {

    try{

      File convFile = new File(report.getOriginalFilename());
      convFile.createNewFile();
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(convFile);
      fos.write(report.getBytes());
      fos.close();

      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(convFile.getAbsolutePath());

      XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument(fis);

      List<XWPFTable> tables =docx.getTables();

      invokeUpdate(ADD_REPORT,new Object[]{

                                           tables.get(0).getRow(1).getCell(0),
                                           tables.get(1).getRow(0).getCell(0),
                                           tables.get(2).getRow(0).getCell(0),
                                           tables.get(3).getRow(2).getCell(1),
                                           tables.get(4).getRow(1).getCell(1)});

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

Here are my Apache Dependencies in my pom.xml :

For Apache POI i have these :

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
      <version>3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
      <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Can you show us your dependencies ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace your apache poi version from 3.7 to 3.17.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
      <version>3.17</version>
</dependency>
```

The latest stable release is Apache POI 3.17

Comment: Thank you that Solved my Problem !